# Should I pass useSelector to useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Hello guys I have question regarding which method you prefer:

In a React functional component with TypeScript, that gets values from Redux State using useSelector is:
1)

```
 const campaign = useSelector(campaignSelector);
 const [audienceSample, setAudienceSample] = useState<number | null>((campaign || 
  {max_completes_total: null})['max_completes_total']);
```

from 
2)

```
 const campaign = useSelector(campaignSelector);
  const [audienceSample, setAudienceSample] = useState<number | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setAudienceSample(campaign.max_completes_total)
     },[campaign])
```

I know 1 is less code but do you think it is faster and which one would you prefer
thank you guys

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The first is invalid. And it is invalid because state from `useState` is persistent, and the argument which is set in `useState` is **default** value, what means - it will be set only when component mounts for the first time. So changing the redux state and new value given from `useSelector` will not effect the local state, it will indicate all the time the original default value.

Answering your question - the answer is not about what I prefer, but what works, the second is just the proper one. However what I would propose here as the best solution from the code perspective is to merge little bit both, in order to avoid setting null as default and setting generic types in `useState`. Consider following code:

```
const campaign = useSelector(campaignSelector);
const [audienceSample, setAudienceSample] = useState(campaign?.max_completes_total); // set campaign as default

useEffect(() => {
   setAudienceSample(campaign?.max_completes_total)
},[campaign]) // set the relation between redux campaign and local state
```

Additionally as you see I have used [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) in order to simplify the code. The type of the local state will automatically be inferred as `number | undefined`.

Above all as I understood your case is to have a relation between redux and local state, then the second is the only option. If your intention was to set only the default value, then using `useEffect` is not needed at all.

Comment: won't you get "React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: a, b ,c. Either include them or remove the dependency array." warning?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason for you to use useSelector and useState hooks together are the re-renders ie. the component should be able to able to re-render when there is a change in state of redux store. But useSelector also has re-rendering capabilty ie.  the component dependent on value obtained from useSelector hook, will also re-render.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function MyComponent() {
  // Using useSelector to select data from the Redux store
  const dataFromRedux = useSelector(state => state.someData);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Render using dataFromRedux */}
      <p>Data from Redux: {dataFromRedux}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

So you can see that the component is having ***dataFromRedux*** coming from redux store, so whenever ***dataFromRedux*** changes , the component will re-render. If it's not then there must be some error in logic of the reduxSlice.

```
 const campaign = useSelector(campaignSelector);
```

so u can directly use ***campaign*** whenever u want to re-render the component on state change in redux store. If you want to set the default value you can do so by changing the inititalValue in redux slice.

Thanks!